# Moving azure storage containers from one blob to another

Tags: azure-storage

Hello I have two blobs in my account:

- Blob1
- Blob2

Blob2 is empty, how can I take all the containers from Blob1 and move it to Blob2?

I am doing this because I would like to use a different subscription to help save some money. It doesn't seem like its possible any other way.

This is all under the same windows live account.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please clarify your question a bit further? In Azure Storage, containers contain blobs and not vice versa. Hence, I am not sure which type of object you are referring to by "containers from Blob1". In addition, I am not sure how a different subscription would reduce the cost. Please let me know and I will try to answer your questions.

Comment: I apologize you are right. I would like to move all contents of my container (ex: "container1") to a newly created container. I have an MSDN subscription so I get free credits every month ($50 worth of azure usage). So my existing container is on a pay per usage subscription. I would like to move it to my MSDN subscription plan to save some cash. But I don't see an option to change a subscription plan on existing components such as azure storage, websites, azure sql, etc. So it seems I will need to create new components with the MSDN subscription and move everything over. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, it's impossible to move existing components to a new subscription.

Comment: As a resolution, I went ahead and contact Azure sales. They were able to reassign the subscription. While not a technical solution (as I still didn't figure out how to copy the contents of a containers to a new container). I was able to get to the end result. Just an FYI you can move a Azure SQL SERVER from one subscription to another.

Answer (score 2):

I am glad to hear that Azure Support was able to reassign your subscription. In the future, if you would like to copy Azure Storage blobs from one account to another, you can use the [Copy Blob REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894037.aspx). If you are using Azure Storage Client Library, the corresponding method is [ICloudBlob.StartCopyFromBlob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.icloudblob.startcopyfromblob%28v=azure.10%29.aspx). The Blob service copies blobs on a best-effort basis and you can use the value of x-ms-copy-id header to check the status of a specific copy operation.